# Calling custom method on add event of collection in Backbone.Marionette

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I am using Backbone.Marionette for my project .I had scenario where i want a custom method to be executed when a model in added in collection.Since i am using collection view and i noticed that Marionette itself does a lot of stuff (like appending content of newly added item and binding to 'all' event etc) So how can i add my own functionality without missing what marionette has to offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marionette has some special bindings for collection and models ([ItemView Docs](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.itemview.md)).

So I think you can just add something like that to your view:

```
collectionEvents: {
    "add": "on_add"
},

on_add: function(){
     //Your logic here
}
```

Comment: I was looking in this doc. It not updated  http://derickbailey.github.com/backbone.marionette/docs/backbone.marionette.html
Thanks for quick reply .